# Netbeans 8.1 Javascript Simple Errors Don't Show in .php File

Tags: javascript, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I just downloaded netbeans 8.1 for PHP and HTML and was editing a .php file that had css, html, and javascript in it and for some reason the javascript is not showing simple code errors like an extra brace or random character(s) where they should not be.

Yet when I go to a .html file and edit javascript it shows all errors including the simple errors stated above.

Code folding, other errors etc. are showing in the .php file for javascript code just not simple syntax errors. I know it seems like a minor issue but it is quite annoying and would love to know if it's a bug or what fixes (if any) there may be.